# django states attibuteError although attribute is assigned

Tags: python, django, web, backend

I have a **Payment** Django model that has a *CheckNumber* attribute that I seem to be facing issues with, at least whilst mentioning the attribute in the **str** method. It works just fine on the admin page when creating a Payment instance, but as soon as I called it in the method it gave me the following error message:

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Vendor/payment/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Payment' object has no attribute 'CheckNumber'
Exception Location: /Users/beepboop/PycharmProjects/novatory/Vendor/models.py in __str__, line 72
Python Executable:  /Users/beepboop/Environments/novatory/bin/python3.7
Python Version: 3.7.2
```

this is my code:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    Vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, blank=True, max_digits=8)
    PaymentDate = models.DateField(name="Payment date", help_text="Day of payment")
    CheckNumber = models.IntegerField(name="Check number", help_text="If payment wasn't made with check, leave blank", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Vendor: {self.Vendor.Name} | Amount: {prettyPrintCurrency(self.Amount)} | Checknumber: {self.CheckNumber}"
```

I would absolutely love any comments/suggestions about the cause of the error

Comment: It's a good pythonic practice to name your model's properties using lowercase and underscores instead of camel case. In Django model property names are case sensitive, and if your table does not have the field `CheckNumber` it will not migrate and will not be usable. Verify your fields actually get properly migrated into their table.

Comment: This might help your coding style: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/

Comment: hi there dmitryro, I tried changing the names properly but it yielded the same error

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you have introduced `CheckNumber` field in the `Payment` models recently with no migration. make sure you run the migration then you can do that using the following command.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This will create a new field in the `Payment` table. Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.
please clean the database and then run the migration command.

To clean the database you need to write the following command(Don't run this command in production):

```
python manage.py flush
```

After the cleaning, you can make an initial migration using the following command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and then migrate those changes to the database table:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: hi there Javed, thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately, I have already done that and it didn't fix the error

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that when you pass a *name* value in a model field, it changes the name of the field with it, I personally thought that it would change the name when displayed in the Django admin. My fix was to just remove the *name* value and migrate, that fixed it for me.